# How to update state according to received props in runtime in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's imagine there are 2 React Native components < Parent> and < StarRating>.

< Parent> is container that keeps rating value (from 1 to 5) in its state.

< StarRating> is a component that renders star images according to received prop "rating" OR according to what star is clicked.

< StarRating> looks something like this:
[image]

```
class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating:5
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StarRating rating={this.state.rating}></StarRating>
    )
  }
}

class StarRating extends Component {

  _generateStars(rating) { ... }; //return an array with JSX rect components 
                                  //according to "rating" prop (e.g. 1,2..5). 
                                  //Each component is the star image...

  render() {

  stars = this._generateStars(this.props.rating); // *

    return (
      <View>
        {stars}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

In case < StarRating> received new prop "rating" its Render function automatically calls with new prop and everything is ok, we see updated stars images.

Each star wrapped to < TouchableOpacity> element and **what should I do** if I click to some star and < StarRating> should be re-rendered itself with new count of stars. In this case I can't change "this.props.rating" inside < StarRating> directly (see * above). I think I have to use setState() inside < StarRating> but how < StarRating> can understand which way Render should be... according to new state or to new received prop? I mean how can I determine in Render function is new prop received or click generated?

It is looks like < StarRating> should have 2 way to update its own stars:

1. through new props from parent.
2. through click on a star inside itself.

What approach should be in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0_) is a pretty good piece written by the author of redux on react best practices with presentational vs container components (also sometimes called smart vs dumb components). Star rating is a "dumb" component

Comment: @SoZettaSho "404 We couldn’t find this page."

Comment: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let `StarRating` manage this state, but your approach is also viable, depending on the situation.

You can pass an `updateRating` function through your parent, and then you can control the rating from StarRating without moving the state into it.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating:5
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StarRating rating={this.state.rating} 
        updateRating={(rating) => this.setState({rating})} 
        />
    )
  }
}

class StarRating extends Component {

  _generateStars(rating, updateRating) {
      // Generate stars with custom onPress
      // <Star onPress={() => updateRating(starIndex)} />
  }

  render() {

  stars = this._generateStars(this.props.rating, this.props.updateRating); // *

    return (
      <View>
        {stars}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to do the same functionality but without double call of Render() (one call in Parent (setState...) and one more in StarRating (due to new props received))? I mean if user clicked on a star only StarRating calls Render(), without calling Render() in Parent through setState({rating})? Thanks.

Comment: It's an ok render cycle, I don't feel a need to optimize it further. If you REALLY want to, you can move the state into StarRating but you will gain 0 performance enhancement from that. It is possible though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you confused is WHO should control the state of `rating` (indicate the different star image).

I think parent component should control this state, because the child component (StarRating) is just a view reflect the state of `rating`, he does not care what the meaning of this state, who should care the state meaning is his parent (Parent).

Also, control all children `rating` states in parent is easy to extend function in the future.

Comment: So, guys, in both cases do you mean the life cycle of click event should be:
1. User click to a star (star is placed inside of StarRating of course).
2. StarRating generate callback to Parent with data which star was pressed.
3. Parent "save" star count in its state according to callback data.
4. Parent generate setState with new rating (star count), Parent Render function is called.
5. StarRating update star number with new prop received.

Comment: And all this means StarRating is "stupid" component and it never nothing knows about its own star count, so it should be wrapped by another component which knows all about current state? Is it correct understanding?

Comment: The second comment is correct , StarRating is a "stupid" component to some degrees, and this way is better to leverage the concepts of "props" and "state".  And  I think it is not necessary to wrap "TouchableOpacity" in StarRating, it could exist in Parent , StarRating is just a image view which render a star image by different props, he has no responsibility to respond to your click. Thanks!

Comment: I mean to wrap StarRating in TouchableOpacity in Parent

Comment: thanks, but "TouchableOpacity" in StarRating is needed to determinate which star is pressed (first, second...).

Comment: is there a possibility to do the same functionality but without double call of Render() (one call in Parent (setState...) and one more in StarRating (due to new props received))? I mean if user clicked on a star should be only one call of Render() in StarRating, without calling Render() in Parent through setState({rating}). Thanks.